# Preciso pegar a ID de um dos elementos dentro de uma combobox

Tags: aplicação-web, navegador-de-internet, combobox, xpath

Tenho o seguinte X path : `//*[@id="selectDashboard"]` dentro desse tem alguns ID's que seriam de determinadas Dashboard´s, como faço para pegar esses caras dentro do Xpath? 
Codigo HTML da dashboard com uma ID dentro dela: e também considere que isso é uma combobox

```html
<option value="8" title="Overview of application activity on your network" lastviewed="1510593168860" dashboarddesc="Overview of application activity on your network" isshared="false" selected="">Application Overview</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

Para pegar um elemento atraves da xpath usando o id basta fazer da segunte forma

`//option[@id="iddesejado"]`

caso ainda queira filtrar mais voce pode usar

`//option[@id="iddesejado"][@value="checked"]`

voce pode adicionar quantos parametros quiser .

Comment: pelo que entendi, o amigo nao quer pegar a opção pelo id dela, ele quer o ID da opção que ele selecionou.

Comment: Valeu amigo deu certo!

Answer (score 0):

No exemplo abaixo voce manipula o atributo ID da option selecionada.

```
$('#exemplo').change(function() {
    var valor = this.value;
    var id= $(this).find(':selected').attr('id');
    console.log(valor, id);
});
```

Comment: Valeu amigo deu certo!

Comment: aow disponha!!!